# bxSlider Responsive Design - Adjusting Image Size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, slider, bxslider

With bxSlider, is it possible to show different parts of images depending on device?

For example, show this on Desktop:

[image]

And show this on Mobile:

[image]

This image-sizing makes sense from a design perspective because if you were to feature the desktop version on mobile and keep the width and height proportion and keep the width at 100% (as how it's done in the default setting), the image height becomes just too small. Thx in advance.

```
  <ul class="slider" style="padding:0px !important;">

    <li><img src="img/image1.png">
    <div class="caption1"><p>image1</p></div>
    </li>

    <li> <img src="img/image2.png">
    <div class="caption2"><p> image2 </p> </div>
    <div class="caption3">caption </div>
    </li>

  <li><img src="img/image3.png">
    <div class="caption1"><p>image3</p></div>
    </li>

 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can.
You can use css with different attributes for different screens.
Read more about it in this link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Then, you can use object-fit to fit the image for a shorter container:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Comment: thank you! i'm encountering more complex issues now, which i asked here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306159/bxslider-complex-image-control  cheers